# How to Specify Accepted API Params in Spring Data Neo4j?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to understand how spring data converts my POJO to the API params/body and return type. My goal is to have a save endpoint that takes in non generated fields only, but returns all fields. As an example, consider the following class:

```
@Node
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class) private String id;
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private String zip;
}
```

with acommpanying repository

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {}
```

I don't need the `POST /persons` endpoint to accept `id` or `zip`, only `firstName` and `lastName`. However I would like it to return all fields on a successful save.

The first thing I noticed is that if I:

- Add getters, but not setters for `id` and `zip` and
- Add getters and setters for `firstName` and `lastName`

The generated open api docs request body has this format

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "firstname": "string",
  "lastname": "string",
  "zip": "string"
}
```

and if i set `id` or `zip` in the request, it will somehow set the properties in the DB, despite both fields being private and having no setters. How is this possible?

I came up with this solution, which works, but it is reliant on `id` and `zip` being included in the constructor args but intentionally being ignored in the method body.

```
@Node
@Setter
@Getter
public class Person {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(generatorClass = UUIDStringGenerator.class) private String id;
    private String firstname, lastname;
    private String zip;

    Person(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String zip) {
        // If I uncomment the below line, it will override the id with the one passed in.
        // this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

This solution works because of the object population hierarchy, it will default to using my all args constructor. But it is not ideal because:

1. I could easily make a mistake and allow end users to set a custom id.
2. The API docs request body still asks for `id` and `zip`, but setting them now just does nothing
3. The lack of a no args constructor means the `find` method fails to cast the result back into a `Person` object

What is the recommended way to have my api only accept a subset of fields on create, ignoring those that I do not supply when writing to the data store, and then return a different subset of fields as the response. Are projections the recommended way to handle custom responses on default `CrudRepository` methods?

NB: I am aware that I need to use `config.exposeIdsFor(Person.class);` and am doing so. I am also awa

Comment: What is the controller endpoint and how are you calling the repository save function

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I am posting to `/person`. Because my person repository extends `CrudRepository`spring-data is invoking the save method for me automatically

Comment: but there will be some controller and service right? If yes, can you please add that as well

Comment: Ideally your request body modal should be different from your database entity

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I have not defined a controller or servjce for this class. As far as i understand it, extending crud repository automatically generates the required Controller and Service.

Comment: You are right in that I could define two distinct types for the type and the modal, but i feel as if what I am doing is rather standard. Given that auto generated ids are a first class citizen of spring data, I don’t see why there isn’t a way to exclude it automatically from the request body

Comment: Try adding `@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)` on id and zip fields

Comment: Hi @CharchitKapoor that did not work. I landed up just building my own implementation of the service and controller. But I am still interested in how to do this automatically as the question originally asks.